# Sharp architecture, how and where do I implement queries?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, s#arp-architecture

I need help with implementing validation logic for users. I need to check whether the password entered by the user matches the `passwordhash` inside a SQL Server user table.

The big question for me is, where do I implement this validation logic?

You can see my user implementation below:

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual string Hash { get; set; }
    public virtual string Salt { get; set; }
}

public interface IUserTasks
{
    List<User> GetAll();
    User Get(int id);
    User CreateOrUpdate(User user);
    void Delete(int id);
    bool Validate(string username, string password);
}

public class UserTasks : IUserTasks
{
    private readonly IRepository<User> _userRepository;
    private readonly IValidateHashQuery _validateHashQuery;

    public UserTasks(IRepository<User> userRepository, IValidateHashQuery validateHashQuery)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _validateHashQuery = validateHashQuery;
    } 

    public List<User> GetAll()
    {
        return _userRepository.GetAll().ToList();
    }

    public User Get(int id)
    {
        return _userRepository.Get(id);
    }

    public User CreateOrUpdate(User user)
    {
        return _userRepository.SaveOrUpdate(user);
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        var entity = _userRepository.Get(id);

        if(entity != null)
        {
            _userRepository.Delete(entity);
        }
    } 

    public bool Validate(string username, string password)
    {
        return _userRepository.PerformQuery(_validateHashQuery) != null ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Do need to implement the validation logic inside the `Task` implementation or do I need to create a new query object inside my domain and use it in my `Task` implementation?

I really need help with this, looking forward to your replies!

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Its an age old argument and one I've fought with myself before.

Take Sharp arch's lead. They solve these problems with attributes check out their DomainSignatureAttrribute, for solving an object's persistence uniquness.

For me, this is domain logic. Tasks are for orchestrating one or more events in a request.

I'd inject a repository interface into your core object and do the checking there:

```
public User(IUserRepsoitory userRepository)
{
 this.userRepsoitory = userRepository;
}

public void IsValid()
{
 return userRepository.IsPsswordValid(this);
}
```

I dont see how this breaks any rules. [This generally isnt recommended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model).

Comment: But where are the Query objects for then? I thought these object where used to perform custom queries...

Comment: Are you talking about http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html? Then follow exactly the same pattern for repository injection and create IQuery objects (IUserQueries) and inject that into your User constructor

Comment: The problem is that the IQuery interfaces does not support parameters to the ExecuteQuery method. The article you send looks great, i will take some time to read it.

Comment: and how do you acces the object on wich you can call the QueryOver method?

Comment: your implementation of IUserRepository is UserRepository : Respository<User>, IUserRepository, where Respository<T> is sharp arch's repository implementation. This gives you an nhibernate ISession as part of that object so you would simply call this.Session.QueryOver<User>()...

Comment: i have tried to implement your example but the Repository<User> does not exists. There is an interface IRepository<T> wich i can implement on my UserRepository class, but i would not give me the ISession object...

Comment: sorry, its UserRepository : NHibernateRespository<User>. this has the Session object

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the IRepository.PerformQuery(IQuery query) has been removed from latest build of SA, in favor of using [Enhanced query object.](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/enhanced-query-object.html)

```
public class ValidateHashQuery : IValidateHashQuery
{
    public bool Validate(string  username, string password)
    {
        ISession nhSession = NHibernateSession.Current;
        // you now have your session and run your query however you like
    }
}

public class UserTasks : IUserTasks
{
    private readonly IRepository<User> _userRepository;
    private readonly IValidateHashQuery _validateHashQuery;

    public UserTasks(IRepository<User> userRepository, IValidateHashQuery         validateHashQuery)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _validateHashQuery = validateHashQuery;
    } 

    public List<User> GetAll()
    {
        return _userRepository.GetAll().ToList();
    }

    public User Get(int id)
    {
        return _userRepository.Get(id);
    }

    public User CreateOrUpdate(User user)
    {
        return _userRepository.SaveOrUpdate(user);
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        var entity = _userRepository.Get(id);

        if(entity != null)
        {
            _userRepository.Delete(entity);
        }
    } 

    public bool Validate(string username, string password)
    {
        return _validateHashQuery.Validate(username, password);
    }
}
```

But looking at your user tasks, it doesn't seem to be doing anything other than calling the repository, not sure what value that brings why not just use the repository directly?

Same goes for the validate query, you could add that dependency to your controller and call the user validation query directly from there, and set cookie/session according to result.
Then before performing a task that requires a user to be logged in, you check for that cookie (Ideally some attribute on the action [Autherise]). Depending on your scenario you might want to have that authorisation in the task itself.

Comment: Thanks alot for your example and explanation. I'm just getting started with Sharp Architecture and everything that comes to it, so please forgive my mistakes! I just bought the book "NHibernate in Action" to learn more. I will give your example a try and see how it works!